# Want to make the zipcode section responsive in every dimension of screen

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd, zipcode

My website name is [bookslab.in](http://www.bookslab.in). It is an ecommerce magento website. My website is responsive except my zipcode section. I want to make that zipcode section responsive in each & every screen of computer like my other pages & sections of my website. I am having the exception for this zipcode section. Any stacky can go to my website & check it out for better understanding. I am facing the problem in mobile & tablet screens. So any help will be appreciated. I had also attached the screenshot. I had also provided the css file & code of this zipcode section.

cod.phtml

```
<?php
/**************************************
 */

$msgData = Mage::helper('netgo_cod')->getConfigData(); 
if($msgData['zip_status'] == 1){
?>
<div class="input-box">
    <div class="z-btn">
        <label>Zip Code : </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style='color:black; font-size:12px'>
        <button type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check"><span><span>Check</span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div id="cod_msg"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function checkCOD(){
             var zipcode;
        var cod = $('cod').value;
        if(cod == ''){
            $('cod_msg').update('<span class="cod-error"><?php echo $msgData['emp_msg']; ?></span>');
            return
        }else{
            $('cod_msg').update('<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl( Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true ).'media/cod/img/ajax-loader-2.gif';?>">'); 
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'netgo/cod/check';?>', {
                method:'post',
                parameters: {zipcode: cod}, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                    $('cod_msg').update(response);

                    if(response.search('Delivery of the book is not available on the above pincode')!=-1)
                                        {
                                          zipcode='checked';
                                          jQuery('.btn-cart').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
                                        }
                                      else
                                      {
                                      jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr('disabled');

                                      }

                },
                onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

css file:

```
/***************************************
 */


div.product-view .add-to-cart{
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
div.product-view .add-to-cart-buttons {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 82%;
}
.z-btn label {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/van-icon.png") no-repeat scroll right 2px top 3px / 96% auto;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 37px;
}
.z-btn input.product-custom-option {
    border: 0 none;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: auto;
}


.z-btn {
    background: #ff0000 url("img/pr-opt-bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 10px 15px 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.z-btn button {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: right !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    /*margin-top: -31px;*/
    position: absolute;
}

.input-box > div#cod_msg {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.cod-suc,.cod-error{
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color #ccc #ccc;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: none solid solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 2px 11px 3px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -3px;
    width: 100%;
    }
#cod_msg img{display:inline-block;float:none;text-align:center;width:3%;}
.cod-error {
    color: #ff0000;
}
.cod-suc{
    color: #009036;
}

div.product-view .add-to-cart-buttons button#zip-check.button {
    line-height: 32px;
    min-height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try media query

Comment: Yeah i had tried but it is not working, can you suggest me in the code i provided above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

add this code in your css file and check this view how it shows

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 300px) and (max-width : 767px) {

.z-btn button {
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  position: unset;
}

.z-btn input.product-custom-option {
  border: 0 none;
  float: right !important;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 31px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  width: 80%;
}

}
```

Comment: I had checked as you instructed, but still it looks weird in mobile & tablet devices & now the layout has also changed by your css code. I dont want to change the layout

Comment: You mean all three come same line

Comment: Yeah all 3 same line after resizing the screen

Comment: Ok add this code then i will give you updated code. after adding this code confirm me

Comment: I had added your code now go to my website & see it looks weird.

Comment: Refer this tutorial http://www.templatemonster.com/blog/css-media-queries-for-all-devices-and-browsers-including-ie7-and-ie8/ used css based on screen

Comment: I dont have time sir, that is why i asked on magento stack can you suggest me in the code i provided above

Comment: Any answer stacky's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49167/discussion-between-salman-dalal-and-kothari).